# How to throw a UserFriendlyException in angular application?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How to throw a `UserFriendlyException` from an angular component.ts
any examples?

> [Abp 3.4.1   template .net core + Angular]

Comment: You can't. Why not show the error directly?

Comment: when the template get an error it shows a popup: "An error has occurred!!!" (eg: i start the angular project without starting the webapi project). Isn't it an example of UserFriendlyException? or is another type of exception? how can i throw a similar popup? or better, a toast notification (that i like most)?

Comment: It's thrown from Application project, not component.ts in Angular project.

Comment: ohhh bad news :-( so if i would like to show a toast notification i should create a my custom service and inject it in a component? using a directive? using another technique? how would you proceed? what is your opinion?

Comment: i've tryed to throw an exception from the application layer as well.

**throw new Exception("my message");**  or **throw new UserFriendlyException(999,"my message","my details");**

they both show a popup with witten: **"An internal error occurred during your request!** without my messages.
The documetation about asp.net mvc 5.x suggests to enable **<customErrors mode="On" />** but for asp.net core?

Comment: As the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191537/throw-an-userfriendlyexception-in-angular-application/48200213#48200213) below suggests, you can use `abp.message.error` on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's client command. use the below

```
abp.message.error("test")
```

Comment: isn't this only for asp.net mvc 5.x template?

Comment: @alex `abp.message.*` is used in [users.component.ts](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/8eb2944430aa814557112c21769c70231f69b911/angular/src/app/users/users.component.ts#L39) for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: i've noted that an `PagedListingComponentBase` component (or whatever else component that derives from `AppComponent` base) inherits a lot of services. One of these services is "message", so, does it have more sense using `this.message.error("test");` instead of `abp.message.error("test")`. isn't it? @aaron @Alper Ebicoglu